# SQL - return count of a column

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 = 'Y'
```

gives me

```
column1    column2
Item1        Y
Item1        Y
Item1        Y
Item1        Y
Item2        Y
Item2        Y
Item3        Y
Item4        Y
```

From this, I would like to return the count of column1 item as such:

```
Item1         4
Item2         2
Item3         1
Item4         1
```

What code can give me this result?

**EDIT**
After trying `SELECT *, COUNT(*)` I get an error: `Column 'Column1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: You need to try what others posted .. they didn't post "select \*, count(*)" ... and they included GROUP BY .. you didn't apparently ? (and I swear I posted a comment earlier here - but it's gone now? odd)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column1, count(*) y_count
FROM mytable
WHERE column2 = 'Y'
GROUP BY column1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GROUP BY` clause and `count` as such:

```
SELECT column1, COUNT(column1) count_y 
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE column2='Y' 
  GROUP BY column1
```

*(Disclaimer: Tested in PostgreSQL)*

Comment: @bsapaka - You did `SELECT *, COUNT(*)...`. That doesn't look anything like `SELECT column1, COUNT(column1)...` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you

```
Select column1, count(*) 
from table group by column1
```